# inserting an array in mysql to selected records only

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, sql

I'm trying to enter a value in a specific records , I have a code where the user select a course from a drop down list then add students from a table through check-box to the course , the thing is when I'm trying to insert the course ID into the student table i cant choose the students that the user choose !!
here is my code :

```
<?php

include("S.php");
$connectdb = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sara') or die ("Not Connect");
if (!$connectdb)
{
    die('Could not connect :'. mysql_errno());
}
$selestdb = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");
$count = count($foo);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){
    $Student = $foo[$i];
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT St_ID FROM student WHERE St_ID='$Student'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $sql ="INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES ('$_POST[$row['courseID'] . "]')";
    }
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connectdb))
{
   die ('Error :'.mysql_error());
}
echo "The Students are add to the course <br />";
mysql_close($connectdb) ;

?>
```

where `$foo` is the array that contain the students ID that were chosen to add to the course
this is the error that i got :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\AppServ\www\test\S2.php on line 20

Comment: Please clean up your code. The syntax color is a hint. Thanks.

Comment: You are also iterating over one more record than is in the array.  Use `<` and not `<=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES ('$_POST[$row['courseID'] . "]')";
```

It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES ('" . $_POST[$row['courseID']] . "')";
```

Comment: thank you , it did work , but it show me Error :Query was empty ? do you have any idea why ?

Comment: You need to make sure that `$sql` is being set and that `$_POST[$row['courseID']]` is actually pulling out a value.

Comment: I set $sql but still the same error , & I dont know how that this query has a value ! sorry for bothering you :(

Comment: `echo $_POST[$row['courseID']]` somewhere above the query and see what the output is. If there is none it means that there was nothing posted with an index equal to `$row['courseID']`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are going wrong with db structure. In my case it would be like following sample:

### DB Structure:

1.) Student: [uin, fullname, address,...]
2.) Courses: [uin, title, ...]
3.) stud_courses: [uin, stud_uin, course_uin]

### Now when user chooses respective students for respective course lets say 9:

1.) Lets say list of studs checked is: `$chkStuds`
2.) Sel Course ID: `9`

### Steps:

1.) Delete all previous entries of repective course in stud_course

```
 mysql_query(sprintf("delete from stud_course where course_uin = %d", $selCourseUIN));
```

2.) Make Bulk Insert:

```
 mysql_query(sprintf("insert into stud_course(stud_uin, course_uin) select uin as stud_uin, %d as course_uin from students where uin in (%s)", $selCourseUIN, implode(",", $chkStuds)))
```

May it help you alot.

Comment: what uin means here Student: [uin, fullname, address,...] ?!

Comment: uin can be unique identification number or primary key or student's id to represent the respective record of student